# Describe the language accepted by the DFA

Tags: automata, finite-automata

[image: Describe the langauge accepted by the DFA]

Describe the language accepted by the DFA shown above

Comment: Note that you don't need any of the DFA that's inside the outer $ab$ cycle.

Answer (score 0):

The DFA accepts strings of the language $(ab)^{*}$.

Informally, the string $ab$ repeated an arbitrary number of times is accepted by the DFA.